# How to change the interlaced parameter of a .png image?

Tags: image, xcode4, png

My mentor has a problem running an xcode project. He found out that the png images should be non interlaced to compile in xcode4.

Can anyone suggest some tools to make the png non interlaced. I donot know much about the concepts of images.Kindly help

Comment: Photoshop can solve your problem.

Comment: If you want to do it manually, you can use any image editor/converter: you must read the image and save it again, specifying non-interlaced mode (it's the default in most applications, interlaced PNG are not very popular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[smushit](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/) can do that. You can use it inside your application, here is an exemple: http://matthecat.com/blog-lire-11-utiliser-smush-it-sur-son-site.html